# How can I write a query that uses the current system time in PyMySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to write a SQL statement in Python that will use the current system time to query the database.

My database has a date field that is of type `date` so I thought a date object would work for the comparison but that doesn't seem to be true.

My statement currently looks like this:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date`=current_time
```

However that's failing and telling me that my SQL is incorrect. I'm not sure if the problem is with SQL, Python or both but I haven't been able to find any examples online and I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Something like this: `pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.strftime('%y/%m/%d') ORDER BY starttime' at line 1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be better using db servers time? If they are on single machine, there won't be difference in time, but you will avoid timezone and other problems.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date`=curdate()";
```

If you have to use Python's machine time, use `.strftime("%d/%m/%y")`

Also, look for the correct format match in `date` field!

Comment: I'm actually just trying to get the day. Like in the values in the date column look like this `2017-02-25` so timezones won't be a problem really. This is more of a proof of concept so I just need it to kind of "work".

Comment: Timezones are problem when clock tiks 23:01 or 0:01 - even DST can make one day difference in these cases!

Comment: Correct you are! However for now I'm just trying to learn how to use PyMySQL. When I tried to write the statement as `sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=curdate().strftime('%y/%m/%d')";` it just told me that my syntax was wrong and that I should consult the manual.

Comment: You should add .strftime(...) to the current_time variable. Firstly, try to echo it on the screen, so you should get string variable, which is purely in format just like in db time column!

Comment: When you pass something to the sql statement, it should be properly formed string or some integers. Format it before passing to sql!

Comment: Okay that makes sense but I have a slight tangent question Is there a way to pass the value as a command line parameter? For example if I have a variable at the top that says `passedInValue = str(sys.argv[1])` how can I use `passedInValue` in the SQL statement? Because when I tried this: `sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=passedInValue"` but I just got this error: `pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'passedInValue' in 'where clause'")`

Comment: You should reed the manual, it's the basics of language ;)
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=" + str(passedInValue);

Comment: Wait that doesn't make sense to me, what if I have other things to add in the SQL statement and that's not the very last thing I want to append? Like what if I wanted to have a `ORDER BY` at the end?

Comment: The  plus sign is concatenation operator.
Yust add another + " order by column".
The str() is to convert value to string. Because you can concatenate only strings.

Comment: like sql  ="SELECT * FROM table where id = " + str(integer_variable) + " AND id_2 = " + string_variable + "  ORDER BY column";
Just remember adding spacebar in query, othervise in the end it can go like "select * from trable where id=2order by col";

Comment: For some reason I thought the + operator didn't work in Python. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's called concatenation. Remember this word! It is the very the basics of programming!
Different languages use different concatenation operators. Javascript, python uses plus + sign, php use dot, mysql use function with arguments: concat(var_1, var_2, "value_3"), oracle db uses two pipes: var_1||var_2 etc...

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you have a few choices for getting the current (server) time.

```
 SELECT NOW()
```

is the most obvious. It retrieves the current date and time.

```
 SELECT CURDATE()
```

give you the present day. These will give you the date / time value converted to  a string. It looks like `2017-02-22 20:18:22` for `NOW()` and `2017-02-22 00:00:00` or maybe `2017-02-22` for `CURDATE()`.

Here's a writeup on [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) and one on [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate).

There's a lot to say about timezone handling, but you didn't ask that. Hint. Use `TIMESTAMP` data types and timezone handling works smoothly.

If you have a bunch of records with a date / time stamp in them use this to get yesterday's records.

```
  SELECT whatever
    FROM table
   WHERE datestamp >= CURDATE() - 1 DAY
     AND datestamp <  CURDATE()
```

This gets everything starting with midnight yesterday, up until but not including midnight today.

If you want everything in the last 24 h ending right now, use this.

```
  SELECT whatever
    FROM table
   WHERE datestamp >= NOW() - 1 DAY
```

Date arithmetic is quite powerful.

Comment: How would I add that to my SQL statement? That tells me the time but how would I use it as a condition for my `WHERE` statement.